# Can/should I implement Python methods by assignment to attributes?

Tags: python, coding-style

Is there any stylistic taboo or other downside to implementing trivial methods by assignment to class attributes?  E.g. like `bar` and `baz` below, as opposed to the more ususal `foo`.

```
class MyClass(object):
    def hello(self):
        return 'hello'
    def foo(self):
        return self.hello()
    bar = lambda self: self.hello()
    baz = hello
```

I find myself tempted by the apparent economy of things like this:

```
__str__ = __repr__ = hello
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Personally, I think things like

```
__str__ = __repr__ = hello
```

are fine, but

```
bar = lambda self: self.hello()
```

is evil.  You cannot easily give a lambda a docstring, and the `.func_name` attribute will have the meaningless value `<lambda>`.  Both those problems don't occur for the first line.

Answer (score 4):

In general, it's completely fine to assign methods to other names. However, in many cases, `hello` should have been `__str__` in the first place (unless `hello` returns a string in a defined format or so).